# Esc handler ignored

Tags: c#, wpf

Following code, doesn't get triggered when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed. Can somebody give me insight?
I like to change the cursor (let's say from drawing mode turn it into pointer mode)

```
    public override void OnKeyDown(MyCanvas dc, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            _line = null;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the function and verify that it is being called when you press an arbitrary key?

Comment: Thanks ...ok got solved by adding code in top (EDIT:)

Comment: @amitkohan Rather than change your question, put your solution below in the 'answer' section and mark it as answered.

Comment: hmmm. I didn't notice such a link/button when I was modifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@amit's solution:

```
public override void OnKeyDown(MyCanvas dc, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        _line = null;
        dc.CurrentTool = ToolType.Pointer;
        dc.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        dc.ReleaseMouseCapture();

    }
}
```